# Randomly selecting an image from a folder and showing it on the php form but each selection limits the options for the next selection

Tags: javascript, php, html, survey

I stuck on how to put the pieces together about some PHP form problem.

Let me frame my issue:

1. I have to present 8 images using a PHP form.
2. There are 3 different versions of an image (version1, version2, version3).
3. Also, there are 8 images for each version.
4. Randomly make a selection among those 24 images.
5. If the first selection image#1 is chosen from version1 folder, then the next image cannot be other versions of the selected image. So, image#1_version2 and image#1_version3 should not be considered for the rest of the 7 selections. Then, 7 selections and 21 potential images remain. The second selection may be image#4 from version2 folder. In that case, the third selection should not consider image#4_version1 and image#4_version3. Then, 6 selections and 18 images remain and it goes like that until the 8th image presented.

In this direction, since I'm a newbie I'm lost on implementing this flow in a PHP form. What kind of blocks/functions should I write for such code?

Could you please guide me in this case?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). SO is **not the place to ask for a tutorial**. Your question should _show_ that you've put some effort into solving your own problem and should be answerable without writing half a book.

Comment: That being said: A general approach to your problem would be to use arrays. Save the folder names containing your images into an array and remove them from the array after the user selected an image from it. That way you can safely keep looping the array to display remaining images without the risk of displaying ones that shouldn't be select-able any longer.